# Keep user logged in on refresh using local storage with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to use local storage so that on refresh, the user is still logged in rather than being signed out every time. I've managed to save data to local storage using this code (I'm using Firebase so I'll leave a lot of it out):

```
 saveToLocal(){
    const local = this.state.loggedIn;
    localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(local));
}

loginUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();      
    this.setState({
        loggedIn: "true"
    }, 
    this.saveToLocal);
```

How do I now go about accessing the data in local storage and have it set the state right away so that the user remains logged in on refresh? Here's my state:

```
constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        loggedIn: ""
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I hope that this will never be production code? How many components you have? Is this the root component?

Comment: it is not production code just a project that I'm working on on my own. I think it's the way I structured my components that I'm running into this issue. It's a child component.

Comment: Use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, get the item from `localStorage` and use `setState` to assign it to `state`.

Comment: why are you not using server side session to track logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could do something like this. In root component track your user logged in/out status. If you already have localStorage item then you just read on `componentDidMount` value of localStorage and set state depending on that value.

`localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')`

But maybe the better solution would be to use cookies, depending on how much you want to keep your user logged in. With cookies you can add time dimension to whole logic.